# Will the new iPhone 7 be compatible with other wireless headphones?

Tags: iphone

It was not clearly explained, whether new iPhone 7 will be only compatible with affiliated brands rather than free to connect with any wireless headset.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, yes.

The iPhone 7 & 7 Plus both use Bluetooth 4.2 technology.  Considering the vast majority of wireless headphones use bluetooth, this means the iPhone 7 & 7 Plus will be able to pair with them just as previous iPhone models have in the past.

From Apple's [iPhone 7 / 7 Plus technical specifications](http://www.apple.com/iphone-7/specs/) page, under the Cellular & Wireless section:

> 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wi‑Fi with MIMO
>
> Bluetooth 4.2 wireless technology
>
> NFC

Answer (score 0):

Since this was just announced and the technical details haven't been posted, I'm only about 99% sure about this but I would say yes.

I'm pretty sure Apple will follow the established Bluetooth protocol so any headphones or speakers out now should work fine with the 7.

Comment: If you're going to down vote the answer then have the courage to post why and then add your own answer.